# Pandas, select values from column where value in another column is higher then another value in the same column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with columns id,event,timestamp.

I want to select all Ids where event A timestamp is greater then event B timestamp of the same ID

```
id event timestamp
1    a      2021-01-25 10:16:46 
1    b      2021-01-22 10:16:46 
2    a      2021-01-25 10:16:46 
2    b      2021-01-28 10:16:46 
3    a      2021-01-25 10:16:46 
3    b      2021-01-25 11:16:46
```

So in the above dataframe, only id 1 has event a that is greater then event b so I want just a list containing id 1.

I have tried the following code below:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df = df.sort_values(by=["id", "event"])
df.astype({'timestamp': 'datetime64'}).dtypes

ids = []

for s in df["id"]:
    y = df.query("event == 'a' & id ==  @s").iloc[0,2] #select a timestamp
    z = df.query("event == 'b' & id ==  @s").iloc[0,2] #select b timestamp
    a = pd.to_datetime(y) #convert to timestamp so can compare
    b = pd.to_datetime(z)
    if sample in ids: #remove duplicate from entering the list
        pass
    elif a > b:
        ids.append(s) #add to list
    else:
        pass

print((len(ids))) #give count of unique ids
```

The above code works well for small data set but my dataset contains 300000 records and is taking forever to run. Any way to make this more efficient so it can run quicker and doesn't take all day?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) for compare both columns with filter `id` from `df1.index`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", parse_dates='timestamp')

df1 = df.pivot('id','event','timestamp')
print (df1)
event                   a                   b
id                                           
1     2021-01-25 10:16:46 2021-01-22 10:16:46
2     2021-01-25 10:16:46 2021-01-28 10:16:46
3     2021-01-25 10:16:46 2021-01-25 11:16:46


ids = df1.index[df1['a'] > df1['b']].tolist()
print (ids)
[1]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I never thought to use pivot. I've been trying to but I keep getting the ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: Use `df1 = df.pivot_table(index='id',columns='event',values='timestamp', aggfunc='max')` - need aggregate values if duplicates.